# How to reset Google Docs to default settings for all documents

Tags: google-docs

How can I reset all Google Docs formatting, heading, and paragraph style settings back to the default settings for all documents?

Comment: For all documents or just the active document?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise I edited my question. I refered to all documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reset the default styles for every new document:

1. Click on the styles button > options > Reset styles

OR go to Format > Paragraph Styles > Options > Reset styles

2. Open a new document and see the styles have been set to default!
3. [Tips and tricks for google docs](http://www.howtogeek.com/195463/10-tips-and-tricks-for-google-docs/)

Comment: This resets the current document to the styles previously saved as defaults on the account.  If I clobbered the default styles with my own settings, this doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps to reset styles, and set them as default:

1. Reset the styles of the current document with Menu: `Format > Paragraph Styles > Options > Reset styles` [image: Screenshot of menu: "Format > Paragraph Styles > Options > Reset styles"]
2. Reset your default styles with `Format > Paragraph Styles > Options > Save as my default styles`